# MVC model is null on post?c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My view code of GNController

```
     public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (Session["pUser_Name"] == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Login");
        }
        ViewBag.pUser_Name = Session["pUser_Name"].ToString();


        DataSet ds_1 = Fill_Combo();

        ADO_Net_MVC.Models.GN.GN clsObj = new Models.GN.GN();
        clsObj.Branch_SName = GENERIC.ToSelectList(ds_1.Tables[0], "Branch_SName", "Branch_Code");

        clsObj.Branch_FY = GENERIC.ToSelectList(ds_1.Tables[1], "FY", "FYDates");
        Session["pLast_IPAddress"] = ds_1.Tables[3].Rows[0]["User_IP"].ToString();
        clsObj.Branch_DeptD = GENERIC.ToSelectList(ds_1.Tables[4], "Dept_DD", "Dept_ID");
        return View(clsObj);
    }
```

view binded as

```
@model ADO_Net_MVC.Models.GN.GN

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

 <div class="editor-field">

  @Html.DropDownList("cmbLocation", Model.Branch_SName)
   </div>
 @*    fill all drop down *@

  <input value="Continue" id="cmd_continue" class="btnBG_Green" type="submit"   tabindex="4" />
```

on post request the model is empty infact i want all drop downs selected value and text feilds

```
 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Index(ADO_Net_MVC.Models.GN.GN model)
    {

     return View(model);
   }
```

here is model

```
   public class GN
{

    public SelectList Branch_SName { get; set; }
    public SelectList Branch_DeptD { get; set; }
    public SelectList Branch_AcdYear { get; set; }
    public SelectList Branch_FY { get; set; }


}
```

can any body tell me why model is null and i want to get selected feild value and text How?

Comment: The only form control your have shown is for a property named `cmbLocation` (your dropdownlist) and your model does not contain a property with that name. The only properties you model contains are `SelectLists` (which will not and should not be bound)

Comment: as of now you did't bind model with control. As per your view cshtml you can't post those value in model. Instead you can do as form collection.

Comment: but my drop down displaying data sucessfully..

Comment: Displaying has nothing at all to do with binding. You model needs properties to bind to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will show only for first drop down. You apply this for all. You need to add some property in model.

```
public class GN
{
    public SelectList Branch_SName { get; set; }
    public string SelectedBranchName {get;set; }
}
```

And in View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedBranchName , Model.Branch_SName)
```

Thats it!!!

Comment: you are right its mean just adding a string of selected value resolve well can you tell me architecture is going write i mean my method I am accepting this in 2 min

Comment: @NoumanArshad This is a standard one in Asp.net MVC. If you are not binding the model then you should say i am working in VC not MVC

Comment: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` when i do for all

Comment: When you are getting.. At post or get

Comment: post i think it need new keyword

Comment: after the post executeion??

Comment: this need 20 reputation star to talk there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151598/discussion-between-power-star-and-nouman-arshad).

Answer (score 0):

Your model needs to contains properties which can map to the names of inputs in your form. The easiest way to do this is to use the helper methods such as Html.DropDownListFor and Html.TextBoxFor.

For your selects you need a property on the model which will store the selected value e.g.

```
public string CmbLocation { get; set; }
```

Then in your view you can use:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CmbLocation, Model.Branch_SName)
```

Now when you post your form you should see the value of the dropdown bound to the model.

Comment: `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CmbLocation, Model.Branch_SName)` object refrence not set on click button